# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: javascript, python, discord, discord.py

Вот код

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('roles.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        role = json.load(f)

    role_id = role[str(member.guild.id)]
    await member.add_roles(role_id)
```

Я пробовал добавить ctx но так ломается весь код

Ошибка:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fun\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fun\PycharmProjects\telebot_quest\ds_bot\bot_polina.py", line 554, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(role_id)
  File "C:\Users\fun\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Файл roles.js:

```js
{
    "913940251951661056": "938100288651395073"
}
```

Я даже не знаю на что думать. Я плохо знаком с файлами js поэтому я буду не удивлён если это будет незначительная проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если открыть документацию по методу [`await member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.add_roles), то можно увидеть, что он принимает не `id` роли, а именно саму роль типа `discord.Role`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получить роль можно либо так:

```py
role = member.guild.get_role(id)
```

Либо так:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=id)
```

В обоих случаях в качестве `id` принимается значение числового типа (`int`), а у вас из файла считывается строка (`str`).

Так что в итоге должно быть как-то так:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('roles.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        role = json.load(f)

    role = member.guild.get_role(int(role[str(member.guild.id)]))
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

*Ну и учтите, что считывать неменяющиеся данные из файла `roles.json` каждый раз при входе пользователя на сервер не имеет смысла - лучше вынести это за функцию*